# Can not import class ServiceClient

Tags: java, apache-axis

I instelled Axis2 which is running ok. I can see that link is visible: http://localhost:8080/axis2/services/

Issue that I am having is this:

```
import org.apache.axis2.client.ServiceClient;


public class Test {
    public static void main() {
        ServiceClient sc = new ServiceClient();
    }
}
```

> Test.java:7: error: cannot find symbol
>           ServiceClient sc = new ServiceClient();
>                                  ^   symbol:   class ServiceClient   location: class Test 3 errors

I tried with not importing, importing but it is always like this.

thank you.
miha

Comment: Make sure that the jar contains `org.apache.axis2.client.ServiceClient` class is in the classpath.

Answer (score -1):

have you tried using the package instead?
`package org.apache.axis2.client`

As I can see in the following repository:
https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/axis/axis2/java/core/trunk/modules/kernel/src/org/apache/axis2/client/ServiceClient.java

axis2.client package implements `ServiceClient`.